# KeyboardNavigation in a DockPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, keyboard, tabindex

Scenario:

I have a DockPanel (MainDockPanel). Docked to the top is a UniformGrid (TopUniformGrid) with a group of buttons inside. Docked to the left is another UniformGrid (LeftUniformGrid) with a group of buttons inside. Filling the rest of MainDockPanel is a Grid (MainGrid) with multiple controls inside. What I would like when tabbing through the content is to tab into each of the buttons in TopUniformGrid, then tab into each of the buttons in LeftUniformGrid, then cycle back to the buttons in TopUniformGrid. What is currently happening is when I get the end of the buttons in LeftUniformGrid and tab to the next control, it goes to a control within the MainGrid. I have set the following:

```
KeyboardNavigation.SetIsTabStop(MainGrid,false);
KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(MainDockPanel, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
KeyboardNavigation.SetDirectionalNavigation(MainDockPanel, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
KeyboardNavigation.SetControlTabNavigation(MainDockPanel, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
```

I had assumed that setting the IsTabStop of MainGrid to false would cause the tab at the end of LeftUniformGrid to skip MainGrid and all content within. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setisfocusscope.aspx

Comment: I don't see how FocusScope or FocusManager can help